# Matlab Vectorization : How to remove for loop in this?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have following matrices :

```
X=1 2 3    

A=1 2 3  
  4 5 6  
  7 8 9
```

I Want to do

```
for each (i,j) in A  
  B(i,j) = sum(A(i,j)*x)
```

i.e. each element of A is multiplied by vector X, and we sum all 3 elements of that vector.
Can it be done without for loop ?

Comment: Isn't that the same as multiplying A by the sum of X?

Comment: @grooveingandi Sorry, I mistakenly asked simpler version of my problem :). I have edited my question now.

Comment: Could you please roll back your edit and ask a new question? This way, @HighPerformanceMark's clever answer still makes sense, and we can tackle the new question with new answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps ?

```
B = A.*sum(X)
```

Comment: Yes, thinking about the problem would have helped! :D +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** As [@HighPerformanceMark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12072679/232610) points out, you can simply multiply by the sum of `X`, which is clearly preferrable. Below is a solution that does exactly the steps you wanted to do, which may make my solution useful for non-linear variants of the problem.

You can turn `X` into a 1-by-1-by-3 array, and multiply it with A to get a 3-by-3-by-3 array, which you can then sum along the third dimension:

```
X = permute(X,[1,3,2]); %# make X 1*1*3

B = sum( bsxfun(@times, A, X), 3); %# multiply and sum
```